# Excel macro to modify cells when enter is pressed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for some help on a macro to reduce a cells value based on what was entered in another cell. I have 5 columns that I will be entering values into along with 2 columns that already have data. When I enter a number into one of the 5 columns, I want a window to pup up that says "Blah Blah", if I click yes, I would like the value in that cell to be subtracted from another cell that will need to be looked up with information from those other two columns.

Sheet 1:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
1                       5   10
```

Sheet 2:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
1       2   4   6   8   10  12
2   2
3   4
4   5
```

So if I were to type '250' into A1 on sheet 1, the macro would reduce the value in cell F4 in sheet 2 by 250 because that's the value for the 5, 10 from sheet 1. Is something like this possible? There would be more filtering based on which column I type the values into, I should be able to modify that in later.

Comment: No one uses Excel macros any more. VBA has taken over.

Comment: @ignacio your father is from argentina? and your mother is jewish? abrams?

Comment: @Ignacio, Actually, most people talking about macros and Excel today, don't mean Excel 4.0 macros, they mean VBA.  He just wants a VBA solution.  I'll change his tags.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure that you can't accomplish a good enough solution with formulas, because writing a macro will be more work.

If you still need a macro, you will want to write a function around the `Worksheet_Change` event for the worksheet in question.  [This link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx) will show you how to do this.

Be careful not to generate another `Worksheet_Change` while handling `Worksheet_Change` event.  Since part of your response to the worksheet change is going to be another change, precede your code with `Application.EnableEvents = False` and follow it with `Application.EnableEvents = True`.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, thanks. What I'm more concerned about is doing a lookup on which cell the macro will be updating. I provided the example for clarity, but which column/row the values will be in are going to be dynamic and will be changing. So a search of some sort will be needed each time a cell is updated.

Comment: The Worksheet_Change event receives a Range object telling you which cell was changed.

Comment: Right, but I need the macro to do a search of some sort based upon other cells to find the cell that it will be changing. Using the above example, I would need the script to do a search for 5 and 10 in sheet 2 to to find cell F4.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to loop through those values.

Answer (score 1):

For the code itself to do the change, you'd just use the CELLS or OFFSET method (on the Range object).  This would be done in the context of the Worksheet_Change event as Steven posted.