# Excel - Insert "day" on a cell and format it to date with current month and year

Tags: date, excel-formula

I am working on a home accounting template (and could not find any good one :-/), so I am creating one for each month. Both in my expenses and my incomes, I would like to have a date column where I just have to insert the "day" (e.g.: 22) and it automatically fills the rest with the current month and year (or I could set them in another cell).

For example: `22` + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>  would return: `22/12/2014`

If I do this, I automatically get a default date: `22/01/1900`

I do not know if it is possible to change this defaul date depending on the current one or any other value.

I have tried with a different strategy: if the `amount` column is not empty, fill in with today's date: `=IF(A3="";"";TODAY())`

The problem is that I do not always register today's expenses, so I need to change it manually. I was just wondering if this is possible and there is a better way (maybe a macro?).

Comment: Is it acceptable to use another column? Like for example, type `22` in column A and get the date in column B?

Comment: Well, I was trying to avoid that, so if I don't find a better solution I will go with that approach.

Answer (score 1):

You need Excel to modify the cell contents after you press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. The only option seems to be a Macro using the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Please check out [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137365/excel-macro-to-modify-cells-when-enter-is-pressed). I think that will help.

Comment: Ok! I'll take a look at this ;)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with simple formatting and use of controls that are available in Excel. VBA will give you drastically more flexibility, however the request above can be accomplished without learning VBA.

I have included a [sample file here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=67878965202976750707).

Steps to recreate:

1. Create a range of months. I created a range including the current month through 12/2014
2. Insert a combo box from the developer tab. Right click and select Format Control. On the Control tab, input the range you just created and then select a "linked cell". This will insert an integer to indicate which item you picked in the list, starting at 1.
3. Use the attached formula to add the DAY that you enter in the first column and VLOOKUP the month and year from the value chosen in the combo box.

Enhancements: I used conditional formatting to change the text color of the days you enter to WHITE. This way you won't see them. I also included some checking in the VLOOKUP formula: the day you enter must be a number and must be non-blank for a date to populate.

[image: Screenshot of Combo Box solution]

Comment: This way you are getting the date in another column. I asked about this option in a comment and @makeMonday said he prefers to avoid that.

Comment: I saw that. He also said if he didn't find a better solution, he would go with that approach. I'll let him decide. My conditional formatting also makes the values invisible, which may make this solution acceptable.